# How to add content manager rights to all reports in my Reporting Services catalog?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to add the role of content manager to my domain user for all the reports in my catalog. Since I have a great number of reports it is almost impossible to perform this action manually. Please can anybody help me how can I perform this operation automatically, i.e.: with a script?

Thanks,
KLEDI

Comment: I *assume*, then, that your reports don't inherit the permissions of the folder they are within?

Comment: Yes, the reports inherits permissions from the folder they are within. My catalog is made of reports without folders and with reports within folders.

Comment: If they inherit the permission of the folder, just change the permission of the folder they reside in, and "voila!". I very much doubt each of your reports are in it's own folder (and if they are, something has seriously gone wrong with your design).

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to all folders. I have db administrator rights to the ReportServer db but on the Report Services web portal I do not have access to all the reports because I am not a content manager to all of them. How can I add myself  the role of content manager to all the reports on the catalog?

Comment: Ask someone that does have permission.

Comment: Nobody has permission to all the reports. We want to migrate from sql 2008 to sql 2016. In order to accomplish this the domain user who executes the migration script that we have build must have access to all reports in the catalog. This is why we want to find a way to give permissions to a domain user to all reports.